# Drag and drop an image/attachment in selenium using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am looking for the functionality to drag an attachment from one place and drag to text box

I am using

```
browser.action.drag_and_drop(src, tar).perform
```

to do the job but this method is just doing dragging the src element but not dropping to target instead the image is hanging around

Answer (score 0):

Native drag and drop of html5 elements is broken in all of the major bowsers still. https://wpt.fyi/results/webdriver/tests/perform_actions/pointer.py

There are issues reported in chromedriver and geckodriver projects, but no progress for quite a while.

Comment: What is the alternative to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't one currently.